# why can't i use the value of area in volume? i get Volume: -1405824736

Tags: c++

To Create a class called Rectangle with length breadth and area.Use appropriate member function to read length and breadth from the user and to calculate area of a rectangle. Create a derived class called Box form the class rectangle.Use appropriate member function to read height and calculate volume.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle
{
    protected:
        int length;
        int breadth;
        int area;
    public:
        int input();
        int calc();
};

int Rectangle::input()
{
    cout<<"Enter the length and breadth:"<<endl;
    cin>>length>>breadth;

    return 0;
}

int Rectangle::calc()
{
    area=length*breadth;
    cout<<"Area: "<<area<<endl;

    return 0;
}

class Box:public Rectangle
{
    int height;

    public:
        int input();
        int vol();
};

int Box::input()
{
    cout<<"Enter the height:";
    cin>>height;

    return 0;
}

int Box::vol()
{
    cout<<"Volume: "<<area*height<<endl;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Rectangle r;
    Box b;

    r.input();
    r.calc();
    cout<<endl;
    b.input();
    b.vol();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably an overflow. Enter smaller numbers like 20 and 50.

Comment: not working not even on 2 or 3.When passing value of area in derived class the value of area passed is -919949024.

Comment: `Rectangle r;` - You don't need this, the `Box b;` already contains a `Rectangle` subobject. `r.input(); r.calc();` - Replace this with `b.Rectangle::input(); b.calc();`. Though it would be better to rethink the design of the classes, so that you don't have to remember all this dance each time you use them.

Comment: Reading uninitialized variables makes your program have [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your surprise at the output of your program indicates to me that you think the object `r` and the `Rectangle` sub-object of `b` are somehow the same thing. They are not.

Your code suffers from the following problems.

1. You are not initializing the member variables of the classes properly.
2. `Box::input` is not accurate. It needs to make sure that the members of the `Rectangle` sub-oject are input too.
3. Your program has undefined behavior since it uses uninitialized member variables.

From programming guideline point of view, it will be better to:

1. Use `operator>>(std::istream&, Box&)` and `operator>>(std::istream&, Rectangle&)` instead of `input()` member functions. This will allow you to read data from any stream, not just `std::cin`.
2. Remove the member variable `area`. Replace it by a function `area()` that returns the computed area.
3. Update `vol()` function to return the volue of the object instead of printing it to `std::cin`.

Here's my suggested version of your program that should work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle
{
    protected:
        int length = 0;
        int breadth = 0;
    public:
        int area() const;

        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Rectangle& r);
};

int Rectangle::area() const
{
   return length*breadth;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Rectangle& r)
{
    return in >> r.length >> r.breadth;
}

class Box: public Rectangle
{
    int height = 0;

    public:
        int volume() const;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Box& b);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Box& b)
{
   // Read the Rectangle sub-object of the Box and then the
   // height of the Box..
   Rectangle& r = b;
   return in >> r >> b.height;
}

int Box::volume() const
{
    return this->area()*height;
}

int main()
{
    Box b;

    cout<<"Enter the length, breadth, and height: ";
    cin >> b;

    cout << "Area of the Rectangle sub-object: " << b.area() << std::endl;
    cout << "Volume of the Box: " << b.volume() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case your problem seems to be the fact that you are not setting length and breadth for the variable `b`. The `Box::input` only initializes `height` if you meant to use the same input given to `r` then this code might be easier,

```
//modify Box::input to:
int Box::input()
{
    Rectangle::input(); // will initialise length, breadth
    cout<<"Enter the height:";
    cin>>height;

    return 0;
}

...

//Then in main
int main()
{
    Box b;

    b.input();
    b.calc();
    cout<<endl;
    b.vol();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calculating area when you call `Rectangle::calc()`. But when you are calling `Box::vol()`, your variable `area` usher to initialize. What you are getting is probably some garbage value. In `vol`, recalculate area or make a call to `this->calc`. And also you are missing length and breadth.

It is a good practice to initialize your members to some default value is default constructor. One benefit is that you don't get garbage values. You should have a default constructor for rectangle like this :

```
Rectangle::Rectangle()
: length(0), breadth(0), area(0)
{
}
```

And in Box, you should have constructor like this.

```
Box::Box()
: Rectangle::Rectangle ()
{
}
```

Also, I don't think taking input in a class member function is a good idea. You should have `Rectangle::Rectangle(int length, int breadth)` of maybe setters like `Rectangle::setLength(int l)`. Take input and set values like this.